# Magento Admin Chart Style

Tags: css, magento, charts, styles, admin

Is there anyway to change the image rendered in magento admin chart? I basically want to change the colors and shadow. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can find the color in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Graph.php in the getChartUrl() method.

```
$params = array(
        'cht'  => 'lc',
        'chf'  => 'bg,s,f4f4f4|c,lg,90,ffffff,0.1,ededed,0',
        'chm'  => 'B,f4d4b2,0,0,0',
        'chco' => 'db4814'
    );
```

f4f4f4 => color of the background

f4d4b2 => color of the line

db4814 => color of the under the line part

To change this, just rewrite this block in your own module to change this function

[image: Here are a test with other colors]

Comment: Thank you so much! so to add this to my theme it would be something like app/local/core/mage/adminhtml/blog/dashboard/graph.php correct?

Comment: no app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Block/Graph.php I suggest you to read some post about creating an extension and rewriting blocks http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/